# Replacing commas and converting to INT in Teradata with SELECT

Tags: sql, database, syntax, teradata

I'm retrieving records from a Teradata DB. The field "CUST_NO" is type VARCHAR. If I use

```
SELECT CUST_NO FROM TABLE
```

the output is along the lines of

```
123,456
321,654
```

though the position of the comma can vary. I want to remove these commas, and return the values as type INT. I've tried a couple of variations of

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(CUST_NO,',','') AS INT) AS CUST_NO FROM TABLE
```

but I'm getting syntax errors. Could anyone remedy this issue?

Comment: what is the error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`oReplace` replaces *strings* but `oTranslate` works on *characters*:

```
SELECT CAST(oTranslate(CUST_NO,',','') AS INT) AS CUST_NO FROM TABLE
```

But there's no need for removing the comma before the cast, Teradata simply ignores it, because it might be part of the numeric FORMAT:

```
SELECT CAST(CUST_NO AS INT) AS CUST_NO FROM TABLE
```

Comment: Worked a charm. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Please Try to use:

```
str_replace(",", "", $number)
```

Answer (score 0):

Teradata is using [oreplace](https://forgetcode.com/teradata/1421-replacing-a-string-in-a-column-using-oreplace) function to replace character in string.

```
SELECT CAST(oreplace(CUST_NO,',','') AS INTEGER) AS CUST_NO FROM TABLE
```